# RViz is not opening in Windows 10

Tags: ros2, ros-humble, windows10

When I tried to open RViz (ROS 2 Humble) in Windows 10, it showed errors. I installed RViz through ROS 2 installation.I am using Windows 10 in VirtualBox. I also sourced the terminal. Below are the errors:

```
C:\>rviz2
[ERROR] [1700051745.147939800] [rviz2]: Ogre::RenderingAPIException::RenderingAPIException: OpenGL 1.5 is not supported in GLRenderSystem::initialiseContext at C:\ci\ws\build\rviz_ogre_vendor\ogre-v1.12.1-prefix\src\ogre-v1.12.1\RenderSystems\GL\src\OgreGLRenderSystem.cpp (line 1203)
[ERROR] [1700051745.148723500] [rviz2]: rviz::RenderSystem: error creating render window: Ogre::RenderingAPIException::RenderingAPIException: OpenGL 1.5 is not supported in GLRenderSystem::initialiseContext at C:\ci\ws\build\rviz_ogre_vendor\ogre-v1.12.1-prefix\src\ogre-v1.12.1\RenderSystems\GL\src\OgreGLRenderSystem.cpp (line 1203)
[ERROR] [1700051745.148952600] [rviz2]: Ogre::InvalidParametersException::InvalidParametersException: Window with name 'OgreWindow(0)' already exists in GLRenderSystem::_createRenderWindow at C:\ci\ws\build\rviz_ogre_vendor\ogre-v1.12.1-prefix\src\ogre-v1.12.1\RenderSystems\GL\src\OgreGLRenderSystem.cpp (line 1064)
[ERROR] [1700051745.149030600] [rviz2]: rviz::RenderSystem: error creating render window: Ogre::InvalidParametersException::InvalidParametersException: Window with name 'OgreWindow(0)' already exists in GLRenderSystem::_createRenderWindow at C:\ci\ws\build\rviz_ogre_vendor\ogre-v1.12.1-prefix\src\ogre-v1.12.1\RenderSystems\GL\src\OgreGLRenderSystem.cpp (line 1064)
[ERROR] [1700051745.149134100] [rviz2]: Ogre::InvalidParametersException::InvalidParametersException: Window with name 'OgreWindow(0)' already exists in GLRenderSystem::_createRenderWindow at C:\ci\ws\build\rviz_ogre_vendor\ogre-v1.12.1-prefix\src\ogre-v1.12.1\RenderSystems\GL\src\OgreGLRenderSystem.cpp (line 1064)
[ERROR] [1700051745.149264600] [rviz2]: rviz::RenderSystem: error creating render window: Ogre::InvalidParametersException::InvalidParametersException: Window with name 'OgreWindow(0)' already exists in GLRenderSystem::_createRenderWindow at C:\ci\ws\build\rviz_ogre_vendor\ogre-v1.12.1-prefix\src\ogre-v1.12.1\RenderSystems\GL\src\OgreGLRenderSystem.cpp (line 1064)
[ERROR] [1700051745.150674900] [rviz2]: Ogre::InvalidParametersException::InvalidParametersException: Window with name 'OgreWindow(0)' already exists in GLRenderSystem::_createRenderWindow at C:\ci\ws\build\rviz_ogre_vendor\ogre-v1.12.1-prefix\src\ogre-v1.12.1\RenderSystems\GL\src\OgreGLRenderSystem.cpp (line 1064)
[ERROR] [1700051745.150847500] [rviz2]: rviz::RenderSystem: error creating render window: Ogre::InvalidParametersException::InvalidParametersException: Window with name 'OgreWindow(0)' already exists in GLRenderSystem::_createRenderWindow at C:\ci\ws\build\rviz_ogre_vendor\ogre-v1.12.1-prefix\src\ogre-v1.12.1\RenderSystems\GL\src\OgreGLRenderSystem.cpp (line 1064)
[ERROR] [1700051745.152820700] [rviz2]: Ogre::InvalidParametersException::InvalidParametersException: Window with name 'OgreWindow(0)' already exists in GLRenderSystem::_createRenderWindow at C:\ci\ws\build\rviz_ogre_vendor\ogre-v1.12.1-prefix\src\ogre-v1.12.1\RenderSystems\GL\src\OgreGLRenderSystem.cpp (line 1064)
[ERROR] [1700051745.154429000] [rviz2]: rviz::RenderSystem: error creating render window: Ogre::InvalidParametersException::InvalidParametersException: Window with name 'OgreWindow(0)' already exists in GLRenderSystem::_createRenderWindow at C:\ci\ws\build\rviz_ogre_vendor\ogre-v1.12.1-prefix\src\ogre-v1.12.1\RenderSystems\GL\src\OgreGLRenderSystem.cpp (line 1064)
[ERROR] [1700051745.154635400] [rviz2]: Ogre::InvalidParametersException::InvalidParametersException: Window with name 'OgreWindow(0)' already exists in GLRenderSystem::_createRenderWindow at C:\ci\ws\build\rviz_ogre_vendor\ogre-v1.12.1-prefix\src\ogre-v1.12.1\RenderSystems\GL\src\OgreGLRenderSystem.cpp (line 1064)
[ERROR] [1700051745.155885600] [rviz2]: rviz::RenderSystem: error creating render window: Ogre::InvalidParametersException::InvalidParametersException: Window with name 'OgreWindow(0)' already exists in GLRenderSystem::_createRenderWindow at C:\ci\ws\build\rviz_ogre_vendor\ogre-v1.12.1-prefix\src\ogre-v1.12.1\RenderSystems\GL\src\OgreGLRenderSystem.cpp (line 1064)
[ERROR] [1700051745.156208700] [rviz2]: Ogre::InvalidParametersException::InvalidParametersException: Window with name 'OgreWindow(0)' already exists in GLRenderSystem::_createRenderWindow at C:\ci\ws\build\rviz_ogre_vendor\ogre-v1.12.1-prefix\src\ogre-v1.12.1\RenderSystems\GL\src\OgreGLRenderSystem.cpp (line 1064)
[ERROR] [1700051745.156567800] [rviz2]: rviz::RenderSystem: error creating render window: Ogre::InvalidParametersException::InvalidParametersException: Window with name 'OgreWindow(0)' already exists in GLRenderSystem::_createRenderWindow at C:\ci\ws\build\rviz_ogre_vendor\ogre-v1.12.1-prefix\src\ogre-v1.12.1\RenderSystems\GL\src\OgreGLRenderSystem.cpp (line 1064)
[ERROR] [1700051745.157964600] [rviz2]: Ogre::InvalidParametersException::InvalidParametersException: Window with name 'OgreWindow(0)' already exists in GLRenderSystem::_createRenderWindow at C:\ci\ws\build\rviz_ogre_vendor\ogre-v1.12.1-prefix\src\ogre-v1.12.1\RenderSystems\GL\src\OgreGLRenderSystem.cpp (line 1064)
[ERROR] [1700051745.158287200] [rviz2]: rviz::RenderSystem: error creating render window: Ogre::InvalidParametersException::InvalidParametersException: Window with name 'OgreWindow(0)' already exists in GLRenderSystem::_createRenderWindow at C:\ci\ws\build\rviz_ogre_vendor\ogre-v1.12.1-prefix\src\ogre-v1.12.1\RenderSystems\GL\src\OgreGLRenderSystem.cpp (line 1064)
[ERROR] [1700051745.158574200] [rviz2]: Ogre::InvalidParametersException::InvalidParametersException: Window with name 'OgreWindow(0)' already exists in GLRenderSystem::_createRenderWindow at C:\ci\ws\build\rviz_ogre_vendor\ogre-v1.12.1-prefix\src\ogre-v1.12.1\RenderSystems\GL\src\OgreGLRenderSystem.cpp (line 1064)
[ERROR] [1700051745.158850800] [rviz2]: rviz::RenderSystem: error creating render window: Ogre::InvalidParametersException::InvalidParametersException: Window with name 'OgreWindow(0)' already exists in GLRenderSystem::_createRenderWindow at C:\ci\ws\build\rviz_ogre_vendor\ogre-v1.12.1-prefix\src\ogre-v1.12.1\RenderSystems\GL\src\OgreGLRenderSystem.cpp (line 1064)
[ERROR] [1700051745.159126500] [rviz2]: Ogre::InvalidParametersException::InvalidParametersException: Window with name 'OgreWindow(0)' already exists in GLRenderSystem::_createRenderWindow at C:\ci\ws\build\rviz_ogre_vendor\ogre-v1.12.1-prefix\src\ogre-v1.12.1\RenderSystems\GL\src\OgreGLRenderSystem.cpp (line 1064)
[ERROR] [1700051745.159408400] [rviz2]: rviz::RenderSystem: error creating render window: Ogre::InvalidParametersException::InvalidParametersException: Window with name 'OgreWindow(0)' already exists in GLRenderSystem::_createRenderWindow at C:\ci\ws\build\rviz_ogre_vendor\ogre-v1.12.1-prefix\src\ogre-v1.12.1\RenderSystems\GL\src\OgreGLRenderSystem.cpp (line 1064)
[ERROR] [1700051745.159681500] [rviz2]: Ogre::InvalidParametersException::InvalidParametersException: Window with name 'OgreWindow(0)' already exists in GLRenderSystem::_createRenderWindow at C:\ci\ws\build\rviz_ogre_vendor\ogre-v1.12.1-prefix\src\ogre-v1.12.1\RenderSystems\GL\src\OgreGLRenderSystem.cpp (line 1064)
[ERROR] [1700051745.159945300] [rviz2]: rviz::RenderSystem: error creating render window: Ogre::InvalidParametersException::InvalidParametersException: Window with name 'OgreWindow(0)' already exists in GLRenderSystem::_createRenderWindow at C:\ci\ws\build\rviz_ogre_vendor\ogre-v1.12.1-prefix\src\ogre-v1.12.1\RenderSystems\GL\src\OgreGLRenderSystem.cpp (line 1064)
[ERROR] [1700051745.160212100] [rviz2]: Ogre::InvalidParametersException::InvalidParametersException: Window with name 'OgreWindow(0)' already exists in GLRenderSystem::_createRenderWindow at C:\ci\ws\build\rviz_ogre_vendor\ogre-v1.12.1-prefix\src\ogre-v1.12.1\RenderSystems\GL\src\OgreGLRenderSystem.cpp (line 1064)
[ERROR] [1700051745.160689600] [rviz2]: rviz::RenderSystem: error creating render window: Ogre::InvalidParametersException::InvalidParametersException: Window with name 'OgreWindow(0)' already exists in GLRenderSystem::_createRenderWindow at C:\ci\ws\build\rviz_ogre_vendor\ogre-v1.12.1-prefix\src\ogre-v1.12.1\RenderSystems\GL\src\OgreGLRenderSystem.cpp (line 1064)
[ERROR] [1700051745.161170200] [rviz2]: Ogre::InvalidParametersException::InvalidParametersException: Window with name 'OgreWindow(0)' already exists in GLRenderSystem::_createRenderWindow at C:\ci\ws\build\rviz_ogre_vendor\ogre-v1.12.1-prefix\src\ogre-v1.12.1\RenderSystems\GL\src\OgreGLRenderSystem.cpp (line 1064)
[ERROR] [1700051745.161748600] [rviz2]: rviz::RenderSystem: error creating render window: Ogre::InvalidParametersException::InvalidParametersException: Window with name 'OgreWindow(0)' already exists in GLRenderSystem::_createRenderWindow at C:\ci\ws\build\rviz_ogre_vendor\ogre-v1.12.1-prefix\src\ogre-v1.12.1\RenderSystems\GL\src\OgreGLRenderSystem.cpp (line 1064)
[ERROR] [1700051745.162115600] [rviz2]: Ogre::InvalidParametersException::InvalidParametersException: Window with name 'OgreWindow(0)' already exists in GLRenderSystem::_createRenderWindow at C:\ci\ws\build\rviz_ogre_vendor\ogre-v1.12.1-prefix\src\ogre-v1.12.1\RenderSystems\GL\src\OgreGLRenderSystem.cpp (line 1064)
[ERROR] [1700051745.162451200] [rviz2]: rviz::RenderSystem: error creating render window: Ogre::InvalidParametersException::InvalidParametersException: Window with name 'OgreWindow(0)' already exists in GLRenderSystem::_createRenderWindow at C:\ci\ws\build\rviz_ogre_vendor\ogre-v1.12.1-prefix\src\ogre-v1.12.1\RenderSystems\GL\src\OgreGLRenderSystem.cpp (line 1064)
[ERROR] [1700051745.162740600] [rviz2]: Ogre::InvalidParametersException::InvalidParametersException: Window with name 'OgreWindow(0)' already exists in GLRenderSystem::_createRenderWindow at C:\ci\ws\build\rviz_ogre_vendor\ogre-v1.12.1-prefix\src\ogre-v1.12.1\RenderSystems\GL\src\OgreGLRenderSystem.cpp (line 1064)
[ERROR] [1700051745.163025100] [rviz2]: rviz::RenderSystem: error creating render window: Ogre::InvalidParametersException::InvalidParametersException: Window with name 'OgreWindow(0)' already exists in GLRenderSystem::_createRenderWindow at C:\ci\ws\build\rviz_ogre_vendor\ogre-v1.12.1-prefix\src\ogre-v1.12.1\RenderSystems\GL\src\OgreGLRenderSystem.cpp (line 1064)
[ERROR] [1700051745.163325600] [rviz2]: Ogre::InvalidParametersException::InvalidParametersException: Window with name 'OgreWindow(0)' already exists in GLRenderSystem::_createRenderWindow at C:\ci\ws\build\rviz_ogre_vendor\ogre-v1.12.1-prefix\src\ogre-v1.12.1\RenderSystems\GL\src\OgreGLRenderSystem.cpp (line 1064)
[ERROR] [1700051745.228041900] [rviz2]: Unable to create the rendering window after 100 tries
```